# Optimizing Selection Sort with Two Stacks in a Restricted Instruction Set

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, stack

I'm working on a sorting algorithm using two stacks, A and B, and a limited set of instructions. My goal is to optimize the selection sort algorithm while minimizing the number of instructions. Here are the available instructions:

- `sa` (swap a)
- `sb` (swap b)
- `ss` (sa and sb at the same time)
- `pa` (push a)
- `pb` (push b)
- `ra` (rotate a)
- `rb` (rotate b)
- `rr` (ra and rb at the same time)
- `rra` (reverse rotate a)
- `rrb` (reverse rotate b)
- `rrr` (rra and rrb at the same time)

My current algorithm finds the minimum element in Stack A and pushes it to Stack B by rotating or reverse rotating (based on if the element is close to top or bottom) to get it to the top of stack A. Until all is sorted in B. Finally, I push the elements back from Stack B to Stack A using `pa`.

However, this algorithm is not efficient when the elements in Stack A are highly randomized.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to modify or improve the algorithm to place minimum elements kind of at the top and bottom of the stack and maximum ones at the middle (something like 25% of minimum at the top and 25% at the bottom and the remaining 50% maximum values at the center), while also considering the limited set of instructions. The objective is to reduce the overall number of instructions needed when applying the selection sort algorithm.

Comment: This might be more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/. You should probably post your use of these instructions too, as well.

Comment: Are there no 'pop' instructions? The stack just keeps growing indefinitely?

Comment: If you perform some kind of preliminary rearrangement before going into the sort proper, then is the combination really a selection sort any more?  Or is it not important what kind of sort it is?

Comment: Also, by a "limited set of instructions" I take you to mean that these are the ways you are permitted to modify the stacks, not that they constitute the only operations you can perform at all (otherwise, they are insufficient because they lack any kind of comparison operation or any way to observe the stack contents).

Comment: Moreover, stacks do not ordinarily support rotation operations, so what is the essential characteristic of yours that is supposed to be captured by calling them "stacks"? Does it mean, for example, that you're not permitted to read the values of stack elements other than the ones currently on top?

Comment: @IanAbbott yes it could grow indefinitely. (technically speaking, it would be limited to the initial size of stack A, as you cannot add new elements to either stacks other than the initial ones, but theoretically, they can grow indefinitely)

Comment: @JohnBollinger the problem gives you an random set of integer values that would form stack A initially, and an empty stack B. The goal is to sort the integers in stack A (minimum at the top) with the least possible set of instructions possible (ideally, less 700 instructions for 100 random integer). The algorithm is not defined, so you can use any algo you see fit (in fact that's the point of the problem). I tried selection sort, but it not suited for large sets that are very random, that is why I thought that rearranging the stack first would help, but I am open to changing the algorithm

Comment: @JohnBollinger, about the stack characteristics, it is not strictly a "stack" as you pointed, but you can think of it as arranging a set of books (you can ra and rra, etc..), I guess this can help : https://2g2uk.csb.app/

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you also can mix various algos at the same time, (in fact it is advised to do so)